# Is this a correct sentence: "Does passive voice of the original content be considered as unique content?"

Tags: questions, auxiliary-verbs, do-support

Which of this a correct sentence?

> 1. Does passive voice of the original content be considered as unique content?

or

> 2. Is passive voice of the original content be considered as unique content?

Comment: Is there any grammatical mistake in my question.

Comment: Which? Neither.

Comment: Neither is correct. You cannot use a form of DO with another auxliary. The second sentence is also ungrammatical because you have two forms of BE (is and be).

Answer (score 2):

Neither is correct. This is the correct form:

> Is the passive voice of the original content considered unique content?

But even putting it in correct form, without more context, it's sounds like nonsense.

Comment: Rob K, why it sounds nonsense? We are using the right grammar and what else has to be done?

Comment: Do we really have to remove the "as"?

Comment: What about:  Is the passive voice of the original content considered as a unique content?

Comment: Yes, you must remove "as". "Content" is a mass noun so you do not use "a" with it.  You have some content, just like you have some water or some coffee.

Comment: And it sounds like nonsense without more context because it really conveys no meaning to me.